# Use strtoupper into implode?

Tags: php

Is it possible to do use strtoupper or other functions into implode ?

Something like that ?

```
$labelsString = implode(':', strtoupper($this->labels));
```

Or do I have to use foreach ?

Comment: Don't wrap `implode()` around `strtoupper()`, do it the other way.

Comment: strtoupper will convert a STRING to it's uppercase equivalent, implode uses an array, but will return a string, if you implode first, then chain it to strtoupper, then you should be in a better situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array_map() helps you: it apply function to all array elements, then return result array, which you can pass to implode function:

```
$labelString = implode(':', array_map('strtoupper', $this->labels));
```

Comment: Thanks deniskoronets, Exactly what I needed ;)

Comment: Why not just: `strtoupper(implode(':', $this->labels))` makes it much more efficient?!

Comment: Yep, you right. It seems to me, that author needs to call `ucfirst`, so I write array_map(). `strtoupper(implode(':', $this->labels)) ` will be more efficient in this case

Comment: This works well to convert each array element to Uppercase :)

Answer (score 0):

implode needs array input
**string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )**

but **string strtoupper ( string $string )** return string.

So you need to convert the output of strtoupper from string to array.
Then you can pass it to implode.